# $M$ is orientable $\Leftrightarrow$ determinant bundle $\det(TM)$ is trivial

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $TM$ be its tangent bundle. I need to prove the following:

$M$ is orientable if and only if $\det(TM)$ is trivial.

The definition of *determinant bundle* I'm using is the following:

Given a vector bundle $E$ over $M$ with transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta}$, then the determinant vector bundle $\det(TM)$ over $M$ is the line vector bundle whose transition functions are $\det(g_{\alpha\beta})$.

I get the orientability and $\det(TM)$ are closely related since the transition functions of $\det(TM)$ are just the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the change of chart for an atlas of $M$.

Comment: Notice that you did not ask any question in what you wrote.

Comment: You are correct. I edited my message.

Comment: If $n=dim M$, a section of the dual of the determinant bundle of TM is precisely the same thing as an $n$-form. If that determinant bundle is trivial, then it has a nonzero section and...

Comment: Then this means there exists a volume form on $M$, and therefore $M$ is orientable. I guess the converse is also true.

Comment: Of course, you have to make very precise the claim I made that a section of the dual of det(TM) is an n-form.

Answer (score 0):

the manifold is orientable if and only if you can suppose that $det(g_{\alpha\beta})>0$. In this case $det(TM)$ has a $R^+$-reduction, since the maximal compact subgroup of $R^+$ is trivial, you deduce that $det(TM)$ is trivial.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find the definition of $R^+$-deduction. Could you please expand a little? I only have been introduced basic concepts about vector bundles.

Answer (score 0):

A $p$-form $\alpha$ can be seen as a section of the vector bundle $(\Lambda^pTM)^*$ because each $\alpha_x$ is an alternate $p$-linear map $T_xM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, or equivalently a linear map $\Lambda^pT_xM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ i.e. an element of $(\Lambda^pT_xM)$. Therefore, a volume form is a positive section of $(\Lambda^nTM)^* = \det(TM)^*$ where $n = \dim(M)$.

If $\det(TM)$ is trivial, so is $\det(TM)^*$ and since the trivial bundle admits a non vanishing smooth section, so does $\det(TM)^*$, which means that $M$ is orientable.

Reciprocally, if $M$ is orientable, then $\det(TM)^*$ admits a non vanishing section $\omega$, which is a trivialisation because each $(\omega_x)$ is a basis of $\det(TM)^*$ because it is a line bundle. Therefore, $\det(TM)$ is trivial too.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant line bundle is trivial means than there exist a nowhere vanishing $n$-linear alternate form, says $\omega$. Choose a riemanian metrics. If $M$ is orientable, we can speak of direct orthonormal base at each point. The determinant in a direct o. base is then a nowhere vanishing form, and $\omega$ is constructed.  Conversely if the determinant line bundle is trivial  and $\omega$ a nowhere vanishing section . Then we have an orientation by saying that a frame is direct if the value of the $\omega$ on this frame is positive.